# How to save a PeriodArray to list?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have scripts like below:

```
df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.creation_datetime, freq='Q')
```

`df['quarter']` looks like `2021Q3` in format. I hope to get the unique values of date time and store them into a list. How to achieve something like that? I check the [PeriodArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.arrays.PeriodArray.html) documentation but find no clue.

```
time_seq = df.quarter.unique().values.to_list()
```

This just gave me errors like:

```
AttributeError: 'PeriodArray' object has no attribute 'to_list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by:

```
df.quarter = df.quarter.astype(str)
time_quarter = list(df.quarter.unique())
```

It works!